# How to enter password in Modal Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```js
$(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#loginModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    window.location.href = '../index.html'
  });
});

var password;
var pass1="letmein";

password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' ');
if (password==pass1)
  alert('Access Granted!');
else
{
  alert('Password is incorrect.');
  window.location="/index.html";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Login to Forms</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="modalpass" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalpass">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm trying to add a modal that asks for a password to enter a page. The password is only in a javascript file.

What this does is, if I click on the page, it will auto load to ask for a password. when I click outside or cancel the modal, it should go back to index.html. When the password is correct, it should stay on the page.

Summary: by default, the user is on the index page. when you click a page (forms page), it will ask for a password. if the password is correct, it will stay or login on the page (forms), if the pass is wrong, it will stay on the modal to keep trying for a password. if the modal is canceled or clicked outside, it will return to index.

The problem is I don't know how to get the value from the password input box (instead of from the `prompt` command) in order to compare it to the stored password.

Comment: I'm assuming this is just some kind of demo or exercise about learning JavaScript or something? Because it's completely useless for providing any actual security.

Comment: Yes, I know for using password should be using a server side. But would like to achieve this client side for knowledge.

Comment: Anyway, you've given us quite a nice description of what you want the code to do, but you've forgotten to tell us what problem you're having. What do you need help with, specifically?

Comment: "would like to achieve this client side for knowledge"...the ability to implement password-checking on the client side is not useful knowledge, because it would never be useful for any real situation. I hope / assume you mean it's going to teach you knowledge of some related technology in the process?

Comment: I don't know how to use the password that has been set in javascript to be used in the input box.

Comment: In reality, if it really needs to be secured, won't bother doing it with client side. :)

Comment: ok thanks, I think I figured out what you're asking. See answer below for a solution

Answer (score 1):

To make this demo work with the modal you need to do a number of things:

1) create a `<form>` which includes both the password textbox and the submit button within it

2) handle the form's "submit" event using jQuery, so we can run some code when the user presses "Login"

3) get the input value from the textbox and compare it to the stored password value (obviously in a real-life situation you would submit the entered password to the server for a secure check to take place.)

4) make the textbox a proper "password" input (using `<input type="password"...`) so what the user types doesn't shown on screen

Please run this demo to see it in action. I added some comments to interesting/important lines of code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var pass1="letmein";
  
  $('#loginModal').modal('show');
  $('#loginModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    window.location.href = '../index.html'
  });

  //handle the form's "submit" event
  $("#loginForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //stop a full postback

    var password = $("#modalpass").val(); //get the entered value from the password box

    if (password == pass1)
      alert('Access Granted!');
    else {
      alert('Password is incorrect.');
      //window.location = "/index.html";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Login to Forms</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
      </div>
      <form id="loginForm"> <!-- form with an ID so we can identify it, now includes both the textbox and the button within it -->
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="modalpass" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="modalpass" class="form-control" id="modalpass">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Useful documentation links:

- [jQuery Submit event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)
- [jQuery val function](https://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [jQuery event preventDefault function](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: I have tried, the login and cancel works but after a successful login, modal doesn't go away and can't access the actual page.

Comment: Ok. Well the question you asked in the comments was specifically about the usage of the password box, so that's what I focused on. And I think if you spend a moment on google you will quite easily discover how you can issue a command to close or hide a bootstrap modal. You've already written a command to show it, so I assume you can find out the opposite case quite easily. Try searching. If you really still have a problem, then ask me again. Small, common tasks such as that are usually very easy to find by searching online, quicker than asking someone else normally!

Comment: Bear in mind though that currently your code also has an event handler defined which will automatically navigate the user back to index.html whenever the modal is closed...so you might want to think about whether you need to change that as well, and what you want to do if the user closes the modal without entering a password (or whether you event want to allow them to do that - perhaps you should not add a "close" button? Have a think about the process you are trying to implement, and all the possible routes the user can take.).

Comment: Yup, was thinking about it as well, thanks Adyson. I will try to figure it out, if not, I will comment back.

Comment: Look here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#methods and find the hide command...it shows you exactly what to do.